# google maps api places how can I get the [i] of the marker in the addListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to highlight the sidebar, on marker's click

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function() {  
    var viewListLink="trID"+i;
    document.getElementById(viewListLink).style.background="#ff0099";
}
```

The TR has an id="trID"+i

the console gives me always the last one trID20.

How can I get the i for each marker?

something like:

```
this.get
```

but how?

**EDIT:**

The marker click that opens the InfoWindow doesn't work: getDetails(placesArr[i],i);

```
places.search(search,function(placesArr,status,pagination){
    (function(i) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i],"click",function(){
        getDetails(placesArr[i],i);
            var viewListLink = "trID"+i;
            document.getElementById(viewListLink).style.background = "#ff0099";
        });
    })(i);
});
```

I tried to pass the placesArr[i] back inside the anonymous function

```
(function(placesArr,i) {
```

but it doesn't work,

```
(function(placesArr,i) {
```

this neither

Here is getDetails function:

```
  function getDetails(place,i){
    return function(){
      places.getDetails({
          reference:place.reference
      },showInfoWindow(i));
    }
  }
```

and here showInfoWindow function:

```
function showInfoWindow(i){
    return function(place,status){
      if(!!iw && iw._iwId == i){
        iw.close();
        iw = null;
      }else{
        if(iw){
          iw.close();
          iw = null;
        }
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
        iw=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:getIWContent(place),
          _iwId:i
        });

        if (place.reviews && place['reviews'].length){
            showReviews(place.reviews);
        }else{
            document.getElementById('theReviews').innerHTML = 'no reviews';
            toggle_off('reviewsPanel');
            toggle_off('theReviews');
    }
        iw.open(map,markers[i]);
        // showReviews(place.reviews);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: you don't need to change the title to SOLVED, just mark the correct answer as such. if you used a different solution, post that answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you run into variables scope issue, to fix this you may need to replace your code with:

```
( function( i ) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function() {  
        var viewListLink="trID"+i;
        document.getElementById(viewListLink).style.background="#ff0099";
    });
})( i );
```

Comment: Hi, I don't manage do define the placesArr inside the new function. I edited the original post.

Comment: @Sebastian can you show us `getDetails` function code?

Comment: @Sebastian you function `getDetails` return a function so probably you need to call it like: `getDetails(placesArr[i],i)();`

Answer (score 1):

It's all about scope.

```
(function(i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i],"click",function() {
        var viewListLink = "trID"+i;
        document.getElementById(viewListLink).style.background = "#f09";
    });
})(i);
```

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Hi, I don't manage do define the placesArr inside the new function.  I edited the original post.